# Controle de slide(em div) com jquery - função next e prev?

Tags: jquery, div, slide

Amigos, estou precisando montar esse slide onde possa ter um controle, ou seja, botão de próximo e anterior. No exemplo a estrutura esta pronta, mas não sei como devo implementar os controle prev e next do jquery.
Alguém poderia ajudar?

O link abaixo com o exemplo.

http://jsfiddle.net/5v0uL6mb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mudei seu código um pouco:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    change("next");
}, 3000);

var change = function(fn) {
    $ds.filter(':visible').fadeOut(function(){
        var $div = $(this)[fn]('.article-inform');
        if ( $div.length == 0 ) {
            if (fn == "next") {
                $ds.eq(0).fadeIn();
            }
            else {
                $($ds[$ds.length - 1]).fadeIn();
            }
        } else {
            $div.fadeIn();
        }
    });
};

$(".preview .prev").on("click", function() {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    change("prev");
});

$(".preview .next").on("click", function() {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    change("next");
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5v0uL6mb/3/)**</kbd>

Coloquei a mudança de slides em uma função chamada `change`, que recebe o nome da função que vai buscar o próximo slide, podendo ser `prev` ou `next`:

```
$(this)[fn]('.article-inform');
```

Fora isso, fiz o controle de slides parar o intervalo quando uma ação do usuário muda o slide. Acho que é o comportamento padrão, se não ia ficar bagunçado, com o intervalo mudando o slide junto com a ação do usuário. Dá pra fazer o intervalo iniciar novamente após a ação, se preferir.